# MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams not getting populated although i get it from the Request object

Tags: jersey-2.0

Following is the method handler

```
  @POST
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
  public ReturnValue postProcessor(@HeaderParam(LIMSRestAPI.AUTH_TOKEN_ID) String auth_token, MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams) throws LIMSAPIException {
   ....
  }
```

I am using SOAP UI as well swagger UI to call this handler. Debugging shows that the auth_token gets set but the MultivaluedMap has size 0.

I then changed to code to the following

```
  @POST
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
  public ReturnValue postProcessor(@HeaderParam(LIMSRestAPI.AUTH_TOKEN_ID) String auth_token, MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams, @Context HttpServletRequest request) throws LIMSAPIException {
   ....
  }
```

I can then retrieve the parameter map from the request object. But still I am not able to figure out why the MultivaluedMap is not getting populated

Comment: What does the complete request look like? Are you sure there is data in the body?

Comment: yes the request.getParameterMap gives me what I want.. its only the MultiValuedMap which is not getting populated

Comment: The request stream is already read and the values are no longer available. You may need to use either `@FormParam` or you need to get the `Form` from [this internal property](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/8fed3c64d1dc3aae5e4cbd0405cf3420f0461fa1/containers/jersey-servlet-core/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/WebComponent.java#L610). This is a common problem.